# How can OnMouseDown in the parent object be triggered from the child placed on top of it?

Tags: unity

I am learning Unity from a book. The example is to create a 2D memory game as follows (viewed in perspective view).

[image]

The green (background) at `z=5`, the purple diamond (front card) at `z=0` and the red (back card) at `z=-5` for example. The front card is set as the parent of the back card in the hierarchy window.

A box collider (2D) component  and a script below are attached only to the parent.

```
public class FrontCard: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("testing 1, 2, 3!");
    }
}
```

When I play the game and click the back card, the `OnMouseDown` gets invoked.

## Question

How can the `OnMouseDown` get invoked when I click the back card by considering the script is attached to the front card game object that is placed below the back card?

Comment: Does the back card, that is placed as a child of the front card, inherit the `OnMouseDown`?

Comment: Does the card back have its own collider to block the mouse's raycast?

Comment: @DMGregory: The back card is the child of the front card. The back card has only : Transform, Sprite Renderer components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, your very first step should be to [read the documentation for the methods you're using](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html):

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or **Collider**.

Under the hood, having an `OnMouseDown` function tells Unity to fire a ray from the main camera each frame, through the on-screen position of the mouse/stylus/touches. Rays detect colliders.

If your back card has no collider, it's completely invisible to the raycast, and they ray will go straight through it to hit the front card's collider.

Comment: If I read the linked documentation, I would not be able to understand because the documentation does not mention what you said in this answer. :-)

Comment: I bolded the spot where it describes that OnMouseDown is called based on colliders. Don't underestimate your ability to glean useful information from thoroughly reading the docs.

Comment: @DMGregory but if people start to read documentation then this Q&A will lose more than 50% of the visitors.

Comment: @Ocelot: In addition, reading the manual makes the learning run slower.